# What is the part of a bottle called where the liquid comes out?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm writing an academic work about pouring liquids with bottles. The different parts of the bottle are very important, because I need to distinguish between the point at the bottom, middle and top of a bottle.
But when I looked up "bottle top" it seems to be the thing that we screw on a bottle. So I tried "bottle tip" in order to not get it confused but I'm unsure if that's the best way of calling that part.

Here's an example in which I try using it:

*The transformation from the middle of the bottle (where the end effector is grasping) to its **tip** equals half of the bottle height in the positive z-direction. The transformation from the glass to the **bottle tip** is known.*

Feel free to correct any other mistakes I might have done in those sentences. ;)

[image: bottle]

Comment: Is *bottle neck* too imprecise?

Comment: Since you ask for other possible mistakes: I think you may be using the word "transformation" when you mean "distance".

Comment: @SimonLRydinMyerson I'm referring to transformation matrices

Comment: I think the sentence might be easier to grasp if you use *hand* instead of *end effector*, even if it is less precise (it could be something mechanical instead of a hand). Of course, if you use *end effector* everywhere then maybe it's better to be consistent. Just a thought. *Hand* can still stand in for other things if it's conveyed as metaphorical, ie. with *italics* or "quotes". ... Oh, or maybe "where the *subject* is grasping".

Comment: @Cold_Class if you definitely mean a transformation which maps the body of the bottle to the mouth, and not just the displacement from the centre of the bottle to the mouth, then I suggest you should write out the linear transformation in full. "Half of the bottle height in the positive z-direction" sounds like just a displacement and not a linear tranformation. If this doesn't make sense, perhaps consider posting a question on math.stackexchange about how best to phrase what you mean, as I think I may have gone beyond what counts as the English language ;-)

Comment: @SimonLRydinMyerson I mean a coordinate transformation, not a body transformation. And you're right, it is a simple displacement in this case, as they lie in the same coordinate system, I'm just mentioning that in the text before writing the whole transformation formula out completely.

Comment: @HotLicks and Lawrence: answer in answers, not in comments. Comments don't have the quality assurance mechanisms that answers do.

Comment: @V2Blast - Comments aren't as much of a pain in the ass to submit.

Comment: @Cold_Class ok, so it is just some change of coordinates which you define, and not a mapping between two parts of the bottle. If you're interested, maybe phrases like "change of coordinates" or "displacement in the z-direction" could make this clearer. But it sounds like in context it is clear anyway!

Answer (score 51, accepted):

I think you are looking for [rim](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rim?q=Rim)

> the outer, often curved or circular, edge of something.

Or more simply , mouth, as shown in the picture below.

[Mouth](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouth):

> c : the opening of a container, *the mouth of a bottle.* (M-W)

[image]

Comment: Since "rim" sound like "edge" to me, I prefer "mouth" because I'm writing about the center point. So do you think `The transformation from the glass to the bottle mouth is known.` sounds good?

Comment: I think it can be easily understood.

Comment: @Cold_Class it parses, but I can't imagine a use for that phrase.

Comment: Note the similarity of the terms to the human head: _neck_, _lip_, _mouth_, and the bottle as a whole to the human body: _shoulder_, _body_.

Comment: @Cold_Class What exactly is “The transformation from the glass to the bottle mouth is known” supposed to mean? As fectin says, it can be grammatically parsed, but it doesn’t make much sense, at least not without context. “The transformation is known” is a very strange thing to say, and I cannot think of anything that could be transformed from “the glass” (which glass? Are you talking about the material the bottle is made of, or the glass that you pour the liquid into? Or something else?) to the mouth of the bottle.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm talking about a [mathematical transformation](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation)

Comment: @Cold_Class: as a physicist I have a hard time understanding this sentence. A transformation is a mathematical relation between coordinates  - here you mention that there is a transformation (= an equation, basically) between "the glass" (I do not know what this is) to the mouth (which has, i assume, well defined coordinates in some referential)

Comment: @WoJ you assume correctly...but now I still don't really know which part of the sentence does not make sense to you :D both the glass and the mouth are coordinates, but perhaps not in the same coordinate system.

Comment: @Cold_Class you mean that you make a transformation of the body of the bottle (all points which make out the glass part) into the mouth, a 2D ring? If so you may consider being more explicit (except if it is at from the context)

Comment: @Cold_Class The glass and the mouth are not coordinates, they are spatial regions. "The glass" is the entire volume of the bottle, perhaps not including its contents, and "the mouth" is the top volume, or perhaps the 2D empty space inside the top of the bottle. If you want to refer to specific coords, you should specify "the center of the top of the bottle". And if you meant the regions, you should use specific language as I did.

Comment: @mbomb007 thanks, good point - I'll do that!

Comment: @Cold_Class Is "translation" or "offset" what your are looking for?

Answer (score 55):

This is the **mouth** of the bottle.

> **3** : something that resembles a mouth especially in affording entrance or exit: such as
>
> *[...]*
>
> c. : the opening of a container • the *mouth* of a bottle

from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mouth)

Comment: This suggestion was posted about one hour before this answer was posted.

Comment: @user110518 Your answer suggests "rim" as the answer, and "mouth" as a possible alternative. I don't suggest "rim".

Comment: Yes, I wrote rim ***or*** mouth. Anyway it’s ok

Comment: When the liquid comes out of the mouth (or top) of the bottle, it flows across or passes the rim.  It doesn't come out of the rim.

Comment: My first thought was 'the **opening** of the bottle' – a word used in MW's definition. That's another possibility.

Comment: Or more technically "aperture".

Comment: @mattdm - That's probably too technical for a beer bottle, although it might work for a wine bottle ;-)

Comment: @J.R.: not more technical than "transformation" (= translation + rotation) in the original quote. In fact, in this very scientific context "aperture" is perhaps the best term... (Except, for bottles which have the narrowest point of the neck not at the rim, "aperture" should probably be applied to that point...)

Comment: @Zeus - My second comment was really meant to be nothing more than a joke on the difference between the way beer-drinkers might talk versus the way wine-drinkers might talk.

Answer (score 17):

The part of a bottle or other vessel from which liquids or powders etc may be poured is often called a 'spout'.

> a tube-shaped opening that allows liquids to be poured out of a
>   container

[Spout (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spout)

Examples

US patent application "a bottle cap for cutting a seal attached to a spout of a bottle to seal an opening of a bottle."

[BOTTLE CAP FOR CUTTING SEAL ATTACHED TO SPOUT OF BOTTLE](http://www.freepatentsonline.com/y2013/0299447.html)

Fleming had slipped in a puddle of water which had leaked from the spout of a bottle of spring water that sat upon one of the store's shelves.

[Munford, Inc. v. Fleming (Legal case)](https://law.justia.com/cases/mississippi/supreme-court/1992/07-ca-59432-1.html)

Comment: Teapots have spouts, as do watering cans, but I'm pretty sure I've never heard the mouth of a bottle called that.

Comment: @Useless - Maybe you haven't spoken with the right bottles.

Comment: The most plausible interpretation of that Munford case is that the bottle is one of the large ones with a spigot near the base. _That_ might be called a spout, but it's not the mouth of the bottle (which is still on top assuming it exists at all)

Answer (score 11):

the **finish**  re:  [containers](https://freundcontainer.com/anatomy-of-a-bottle/) Freund Bottles Co.

> the finish can best be described as ‘the lip of the bottle’. The term
>   "finish" originated when glass bottles were still produced by mouth
>   blown craftsman and the last step in completing a finished bottle was
>   to "finish the lip."

And more, with some confusion:  [bottle morphology](https://sha.org/bottle/morphology.htm)

> **Finish** - Simply put, the finish is typically everything above the distinctive upper terminus of the neck.  It refers to the combination
>   of the lip (upper part) and collar (lower part) of a finish, if both
>   are present, or any other distinct parts if present.  The term
>   "finish" originates as a reference to the final process of making a
>   mouth-blown bottle - completion or "finishing" of the lip and upper
>   portion of the neck.  Generically, a finish can have one-part,
>   two-parts (like in the illustration above), three-parts, and rarely
>   more parts (Jones & Sullivan 1989).  The finish on a bottle is also
>   referred to sometimes as a "top" or "mouth" (White 1978),  See the
>   Bottle Finishes page for much more information on finishes.

and

> **Lip** - This is one of the more confusing and variably used terms used in reference to bottle morphology.  As used on this site, lip has
>   two meanings depending on the context, though both uses are better
>   described with other terms.  It is used to describe the extreme upper
>   surface of the finish, though the term rim is preferred (both are
>   often used together on this website).   Lip is also used by some - and
>   occasionally on this website as indicated by the illustration above -
>   to refer to the upper part of a multiple part finish (Jones & Sullivan
>   1989).  The term is also frequently used as a shorthand reference for
>   the entire finish - lip and collar together.  However, for added
>   confusion, the term collar is used by some to refer to what is called
>   a lip here - the upper part of the finish or the entire finish if it
>   is composed of only one part.  See the Bottle Finishes page for much
>   more information on finishes and finish parts.

[image: bottle anatomy]

Comment: thx for so much info :)
I guess my image is not precise enough, because finish is the correct term for what I've circled I think but not really what I'm looking for. I'm writing about the center point of the rim I guess. I just checked some other articles and found a very easy alternative that I like: bottle opening :D

Comment: How about bottle's "top", which would be covered and sealed by a "cap"?  "Mouth" is also a good word for the opening at the top of a bottle.  Of course bottle makers and bottlers--those who fill bottles with things like wine, beer, vinegar, etc.--might have technical words like "finish" described above.

Comment: @tautophile In British English the "cap" is often called the "bottle top" (especially for non-resealable beer bottle caps, etc) even though "cap" is the more correct term.

Comment: This is well-researched and clearly correct, but I doubt that anyone outside the bottle manufacturing industry will understand the term "finish".

Comment: @DavidRicherby—If anyone outside the bottle-manufacturing industry could be expected to understand the term ‘finish’ in this context, I suspect it would the audience for 'an academic work about pouring liquids with bottles’.